# how to add sqlserver's database using hangfire job and entityframework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, hangfire

hi I have hangfire up and running in startup.cs and dashboard is running but i want to add a job to add field to sqlserver database  every minute.can U help me?

Comment: This question is too broad for the nature of this forum. Please read the HangFire documentation and "getting started" and "tutorial" sections first to get familiar with HangFire, and attempt to get this working on your own. If you are still stuck, then edit this question with specific issues that you are running into, and the community will be in a better position to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented a service class to store data to db. which will be used to recurring job

```cs
public interface ITestService{
    Task SaveData();
}
```

```cs
public class TestService : ITestService{

private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;

   public TestService(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
   {
       _dbContext = dbContext;
   }

   public async Task SaveData()
   {
       _dbContext.Users.Add(new User
       {
           UserName = "testUser",
           Email = "testa@gmail.com"
       });

    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Inside `ConfigureServices()` in startup.cs I have registered hangfire with the dbcontext and serviceClass which will be saving data to the database

```cs
services.AddHangfire(x => x.UseSqlServerStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
services.AddHangfireServer();

services.AddTransient<ApplicationDbContext>(); //Your DbContext
services.AddTransient<ITestService, TestService>(); //Your Service to store data
```

in the same file change the `configure` method to,

```cs
 Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IRecurringJobManager recurringJobManager, ITestService testService)
```

inside the above method add the call the following methods

```cs
app.UseHangfireDashboard();

recurringJobManager.AddOrUpdate("First recurring job", () => testService.SaveData(), Cron.MinuteInterval(1)); //Instead of the Cron.MinuteInterval() you can use cron expressions
```